# Can't uninstall 'youtube-dl'. No files were found to uninstall

Tags: upgrade, youtube-dl

`youtube-dl` told me to upgrade, so I tried the command given on their website, but it resulted in some output that sounds like it has not upgraded anything, despite an upgrade being available:

```
$ sudo pip install -U youtube-dl
Downloading/unpacking youtube-dl from https://pypi.python.org/packages/2.7/y/youtube_dl/youtube_dl-2016.02.05.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=2effdf3d1f12908c1d3fb27ab0035343
  Downloading youtube_dl-2016.02.05.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.2MB): 1.2MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: youtube-dl
  Found existing installation: youtube-dl 2016.1.15
    Can't uninstall 'youtube-dl'. No files were found to uninstall.
Successfully installed youtube-dl
Cleaning up...
```

How to fix that and really get the latest version?

Comment: If not really necessary, you should not install/upgrade packages from outside the repositories without the package manager. Especially if you had the package installed, that can lead to confusion, because `pip` probably will install it into a different location than `apt` and you'll end up with two versions.

Comment: @ByteCommander: youtube-dl is meant to be upgraded every few weeks, at a much faster pace than Ubuntu distributions.

Comment: I am not too sure about this specific application, but there are also package updates in between two releases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These commands did the trick:

```
$ sudo dpkg -r youtube-dl
(Reading database ... 332796 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing youtube-dl (2015.06.04.1-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.4-1) ...
$ sudo rm -rf /usr/local/share/doc/youtube_dl /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/youtube_dl* /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
$ sudo pip install --upgrade youtube-dl
Downloading/unpacking youtube-dl
  Downloading youtube_dl-2016.02.05.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.2MB): 1.2MB downloaded
Installing collected packages: youtube-dl
Successfully installed youtube-dl
```